# The service X does not implement the EventSubscriberInterface

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

For some reason I get an exception that my class `SerializeListener` does not implement the class `EventSubscriberInterface`. The `SerializeListener` called as a service on `preSerialize`.

As you can see the interface is implemented and the function of the interface aswell:

**Full exception:**

```
RuntimeException: The service "acme.serializelistener" (class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\SerializeListener) does not implement the EventSubscriberInterface.
```

**Config.yml**

```
services:    
    json_formatter:
        class: Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter

    acme.serializelistener:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\SerializeListener
        tags:
            - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

**EventSubscriberInterface**

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher;

/**
 * An EventSubscriber knows himself what events he is interested in.
 * If an EventSubscriber is added to an EventDispatcherInterface, the manager invokes
 * {@link getSubscribedEvents} and registers the subscriber as a listener for all
 * returned events.
 *
 * @author  Guilherme Blanco <guilhermeblanco@hotmail.com>
 * @author  Jonathan Wage <jonwage@gmail.com>
 * @author  Roman Borschel <roman@code-factory.org>
 * @author  Bernhard Schussek <bschussek@gmail.com>
 *
 * @api
 */
interface EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns an array of event names this subscriber wants to listen to.
     *
     * The array keys are event names and the value can be:
     *
     *  * The method name to call (priority defaults to 0)
     *  * An array composed of the method name to call and the priority
     *  * An array of arrays composed of the method names to call and respective
     *    priorities, or 0 if unset
     *
     * For instance:
     *
     *  * array('eventName' => 'methodName')
     *  * array('eventName' => array('methodName', $priority))
     *  * array('eventName' => array(array('methodName1', $priority), array('methodName2'))
     *
     * @return array The event names to listen to
     *
     * @api
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents();
}
```

**SerializeListener:**

```
<?php    

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\PreSerializeEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class SerializeListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array('event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize', 'method' => 'onPreSerialize'),
        );
    }

    public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        var_dump($event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the [`JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface`](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/EventDispatcher/EventSubscriberInterface.php) instead of `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface`. See the `JMSSerializerBundle`'s `RegisterEventListenersAndSubscribers` [DIC compiler pass](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterEventListenersAndSubscribersPass.php#L40).